# How to add info to request.POST?

Tags: python, django

When a user creates something using a form, all of the info is submitted through a form which is sent through an AJAX call to the following view:

```
def goal_create(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user
    request.POST[user] = user.id
    errors = form_validate(request, AddGoalForm, Goal)
```

I get an error when I try to modify request.POST dict and add a user's id to the model instance. I want to add it, so in the next step (when it goes to form_validate), it will create a new model instance for me.
Here is form_validate, which validates the form according to a ModelForm.

```
def form_validate(request, form, model):
  form = form(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    new = form.save()
  else:
    return form.errors.items()
```

Here is the model I'm working with:

```
class Goal(models.Model):
  goal_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
  user =  models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
  created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Another issue is that even though goal_name has attribute blank=False, and I create a new goal with a blank goal_name, it says that the form is_valid() and saves the form.

Comment: if you're not using the form's user field, do you need to include it in the form?

Comment: I have to access a goal's user in the future. With the above method, the user is null.

Answer (score 9):

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user = request.user
        post_values = request.POST.copy()

        post_values['user'] = user.id
        form = MyForm(post_values)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('error'))
```

**p.s** This is a quick fix but not a very elegant method to use. Though there are no issues when you would use this

Answer (score 0):

forms.py

```
class GoalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(GoalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(GoalForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_goal(request):
    form = GoalForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        return HttpResponse('ok')
    return HttpResponse('errors')
```