# Check is DJANGO object is valid

Tags: django

I have DJANGO model object, not form. Is there a function to check is model valid?

With forms I have `form.is_valid():`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean input strings without using the django Form classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697508/clean-input-strings-without-using-the-django-form-classes)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
instance.field1 = some_value
instance.full_clean()
```

This is called automatically when you save a model via a modelform (eg `instance = myform.save()`), but *not* when you just do `instance.save()`.